# Can not split xml file with xsl, in springsource IDE

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to xsl technology. What I am trying to do is split the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fields>
        <fullName>StageName</fullName>
        <picklist>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Prospecting/Needs/Qualification</fullName>
                <closed>false</closed>
                <default>false</default>
                <forecastCategory>Pipeline</forecastCategory>
                <probability>25</probability>
                <won>false</won>
            </picklistValues>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Proposal/Price Quote</fullName>
                <closed>false</closed>
                <default>false</default>
                <forecastCategory>Pipeline</forecastCategory>
                <probability>40</probability>
                <won>false</won>
            <sorted>false</sorted>
        </picklist>
        <trackFeedHistory>true</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Picklist</type>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Status__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Status</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

to two different files, named after each of the field/fullname - elements of the latter. So essentially I want first file: "StageName.xml" :

```
<fields>
            <fullName>StageName</fullName>
            <picklist>
                <picklistValues>
                    <fullName>Prospecting/Needs/Qualification</fullName>
                    <closed>false</closed>
                    <default>false</default>
                    <forecastCategory>Pipeline</forecastCategory>
                    <probability>25</probability>
                    <won>false</won>
                </picklistValues>
                <picklistValues>
                    <fullName>Proposal/Price Quote</fullName>
                    <closed>false</closed>
                    <default>false</default>
                    <forecastCategory>Pipeline</forecastCategory>
                    <probability>40</probability>
                    <won>false</won>
                <sorted>false</sorted>
            </picklist>
            <trackFeedHistory>true</trackFeedHistory>
            <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
            <type>Picklist</type>
        </fields>
```

and second file: "Status__c.xml":

```
<fields>
            <fullName>Status__c</fullName>
            <externalId>false</externalId>
            <label>Status</label>
            <required>false</required>
            <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
            <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
            <type>Text</type>
            <unique>false</unique>
        </fields>
```

I have wrote the following small script, based on questions-answers in stackoverflow:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
                xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" 
                extension-element-prefixes="redirect">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:for-each select="fields">
            <redirect:write file="file_{@id}-output.xml">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="fields"/>
            </redirect:write>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and what I am getting is the following one and only file: "Opportunity.out.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


        StageName


                Prospecting/Needs/Qualification
                false
                false
                Pipeline
                25
                false


                Proposal/Price Quote
                false
                false
                Pipeline
                40
                false

            false

        true
        false
        Picklist


        Status__c
        false
        Status
        false
        false
        false
        Text
        false
```

I am running the split.xsl file through right click --> run As ---> XSL Transformation in SpringSource.

I am sorry in advance for the enormous size of question, but I honestly have no idea on where to begin fixing that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the namespace in the input XML into account by declaring a prefix for it in the stylesheet and then by using that prefix to qualify element names. Also the root of the sample you have posted is not `root` but rather `CustomObject` so alltoghether we need

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
                xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" 
                xmlns:df="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
                extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
                exclude-result-prefixes="df redirect">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/df:CustomObject"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:for-each select="df:fields">
    <redirect:write file="file_{df:fullName}-output.xml">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </redirect:write>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run that with Xalan 2.7 Java from the command line it generates output files `file_StageName-output.xml` and `file_Status__c-output.xml`.

So you probably rather want `<redirect:write file="{df:fullName}-output.xml">`. As for getting that to work with your IDE, tag your question with a tag related to that IDE so that hopefully someone familiar with it can help.

Comment: Hello Martin,  Thanks for your answer.  I tried this solution, but I am still getting the initial output I posted. Do you think it might have to do with springsource configuration ?

Comment: @Antigoni, I have edited the answer and corrected a match pattern to work with the sample you have provided (which also needed a correction to make it well-formed).

Comment: Ok @Martin, thanks a lot again. Just two last quick questions: How can I check my version of Xalan, and 2. what command are you typing in the command line to run it from there ?  Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: I followed the instructions on http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html, making sure I had all four .jars on the classpath. There is also the case-insensitive `-V (Version info)` option to find out about the version.

Comment: Hello @Martin and thanks again for the instructions.  I followed all of them, run successfully the command from command line, but still getting an output without the xml tags, and it is not written in two files, just displayed on the command line. I guess now, it's down to the xsl file, right ?

Comment: Well the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in the original code and that I kept does indeed call the built-in templates and that way there should be output to the command line of all the text in the input XML. You can remove that `<xsl:apply-templates/>` if you don't want or need that output. The two files should however also be created. I see that the answer has been accepted so you need to clarify whether the problem is solved.

Comment: Hi Martin, the problem is solved, sorry my bad, was doing something wrong and could not see the files. Thanks for all you help !  I have a new problem now, but I suppose I should create a new question if searching in stack proves unsuccessful !